# Beautifulsoup4 не выдает полный код страницы

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Хочу собрать базу пользователей онлайн просто чтобы познакомиться с бс4.

```
import bs4
import lxml
import requests

page=requests.get('https://streamcraft.net/forum')
print(page)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

nicks=soup.find_all('<li>')
print(soup)
```

При попытке вывести soup получаю код без одного блока. Как фиксить?

Comment: Динамический сайт, а чтобы познакомиться с бс4 выберете статический сайт.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Да не за что :) Вот попробуйте для знакомства с бс4 http://rutor.info. На https://streamcraft.net/  плюс еще защита от ботов стоит.